# Error at end of rainfall program

Tags: c++, visual-c++

**My error: Myprograms.exe has stopped working
a problem caused the program to stop working correclty. windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available**

uncertain to why i'm getting such an error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
//Constant to hold number of months 
const int NUM_MONTHS = 12;

void getInput(double[]);
double getTotal(double[]);
double getAverage(double, double[]);
double getHighest(double[]);
double getLowest(double[]);
void displayOutput(double[], double, double);
int main()
{
double rainArray[NUM_MONTHS], totalRainfall, averageRainfall, highest, lowest;

//call function getInput
getInput(rainArray);
//call function getTotal
totalRainfall = getTotal(rainArray);
//call function getAverage
averageRainfall = getAverage(totalRainfall, rainArray);
//call function getHighest
highest = getHighest(rainArray);
//call function getLowest
lowest = getLowest(rainArray);
//call function displayOutput
displayOutput(rainArray, highest, lowest);

return 0;
}
//function getInput - precondition - prompt the user to input 12 values and store them in a array(rainArray as parameter)
//Make sure user cannot enter negative number(use while loop)
//postcondition - the array has been populated
void getInput(double rainArray[])
{
using namespace std;
int counter=0, input;

cout << "Enter the amount of rainfall for each month of the year\n";
while (counter < NUM_MONTHS)
{
cin >> input;

if (input > 0)
{
rainArray[counter] = input;

counter++;
} 

else 
{
cout << "Rainfall must be greater than 0.\n";
cout << "Please enter correct total.\n";
}
}
}




//function getTotal - precondition - access to array of 12 values(rainArray as parameter)
//Accumulate the monthly values(using a for loop)
//postcondition - returns the total rainfall for the year
double getTotal(double rainArray[])
{
using namespace std;
double total = 0;

for (int count = 0; count < NUM_MONTHS; count++)
total += rainArray[count];

return total;
}


//function getAverage - precondition - access to total rainfall(totalRainfall as parameter)
//Divide from the total from the number of months
//postcondition - returns the total average for the year
double getAverage(double totalRainfall, double rainArray[])
{
using namespace std;
double average = 0;

average = getTotal(rainArray) / NUM_MONTHS;

return average;
}

//function getHighest - precondition - access to array of 12 values(rainArray as paramter)
//Store highest value from rainArray in to variable highestRainfall and return(using for loop)
//post condition - returns the highest amount of rainfall for the year
double getHighest(double rainArray[])
{
double highest;
highest = rainArray[0];

for (int month = 1; month < NUM_MONTHS; month++)
{
if (rainArray[month] > highest)
{
highest = rainArray[month];
}

}
return highest;
}

//function getLowest - precondition - access to array of 12 values(rainArray as parameter)
//Store lowest value from rainArray in to variable lowestRainfall and return(using for loop)
//postcondition - returns the lowest amount of rainfall for the year
double getLowest(double rainArray[])
{
double lowest;
lowest = rainArray[0];

for (int month = 1; month < NUM_MONTHS; month++)
{
if (rainArray[month] < lowest)
{
lowest = rainArray[month];
}

}
return lowest;
}

//function displayOutput - preconditon - needs to know the array and the averageRainfall 
//Use for loop to display the amount of months and subtract each array element by the averageRainfall
//postcondition - outputs the month number and the difference between rain amount and the average
void displayOutput(double rainArray[], double highest, double lowest)
{
using namespace std;

string monthArray[NUM_MONTHS] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

cout << "The highest score is " << highest << endl
<< "The lowest score is " << lowest << endl;

for (int i = 0; rainArray[i] <= NUM_MONTHS; i++)
{
double average = getAverage(getTotal(rainArray), rainArray);
double variance = rainArray[i] - average;
string month = monthArray[i];

cout << "Rainfall for the month of " << month << ": " << rainArray[i]
<< " and is " << variance << "away from the average of " << average << endl;

}
}
```

Comment: compiled and ran the program and all of the code appears to run as intended, but at the end it stalls and I get this error: Myprograms.exe has stopped working a problem caused the program to stop working correclty. windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to step through the program and see exactly where the issue occurs?

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x0F56EA8E (msvcr110d.dll) in MyPrograms.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x88EEA7F1.A7F1 is what I got from the debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible culprit is your loop condition in `displayOutput()`. Here's the line:

```
for (int i = 0; rainArray[i] <= NUM_MONTHS; i++)
```

It's presumably supposed to loop through every element in `rainArray`. However, currently it will loop through an arbitrary number of times depending on your input data. It's entirely possible that it's going past the end of your array and trying to access memory that it's not supposed to access.

That may explain the error message you saw. It's hard to tell for sure without knowing what input data you're testing with though.

Try changing the loop to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_MONTHS; i++)
```

Comment: Still getting the same error, my test data is 4, 2, 3, 7, 5, 3 , 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4

Comment: Sorry, the loop condition should use `<` not `<=`. I'll edit my answer.